# Video compressing not working with ffmpeg4android_lib library

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, google-play-console, android-ffmpeg

When I am trying video compressing with ffmpeg4android_lib library then it is working on debug mode(Not google play store app) after that when I check live on play store the video compressing is not working and found that the application crashed. After the crash, it gives the error:- 
**videokitLibPath not exits: /data/app/com.practice.presto-SSicBo_Qm4UXOQAQ45Vttg==/lib/arm/libvideokit.so**
My App Log is below:

```
1576657500.663 20809-20809/com.practice.presto D/MyPracticeAudioVideo: outside wifi file type 2
1576657500.807 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/MyPracticeAudioVideo: Worker started
1576657500.807 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/MyPracticeAudioVideo: new file video path /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20191218_135413.mp4
1576657500.808 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/MyPracticeAudioVideo: Acquire wake lock
1576657500.812 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/ffmpeg4android: checkForPermissions() called
1576657500.814 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/ffmpeg4android: permission already granted
1576657500.830 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/MyPracticeAudioVideo: ffmpeg -y -i /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20191218_135413.mp4 -strict experimental -s 320x240 -r 25 -aspect 4:3 -vcodec mpeg4 -b 150k -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 /storage/emulated/0/pp/1576657432247.mp4
1576657500.831 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/ffmpeg4android: running ffmpeg4android_lib: 41.07.00_LM41_00
1576657500.831 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/ffmpeg4android: {"ffmpeg","-y","-i","/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20191218_135413.mp4","-strict","experimental","-s","320x240","-r","25","-aspect","4:3","-vcodec","mpeg4","-b","150k","-ab","48000","-ac","2","-ar","22050","/storage/emulated/0/pp/1576657432247.mp4"}
1576657500.833 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/ffmpeg4android: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20191218_135413.mp4 length in bytes: 15793157
1576657500.834 20809-22043/com.practice.presto E/ffmpeg4android: **videokitLibPath not exits: /data/app/com.practice.presto-SSicBo_Qm4UXOQAQ45Vttg==/lib/arm/libvideokit.so**
1576657500.835 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/Videokit: libvideokit.so load Fail: /data/app/com.practice.presto-SSicBo_Qm4UXOQAQ45Vttg==/lib/arm/libvideokit.so
1576657500.835 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/Videokit: args is not NULL
1576657500.835 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/Videokit: more then one arg
1576657500.835 20809-22043/com.practice.presto I/Videokit: function symbol not found
1576657500.835 20809-22043/com.practice.presto D/Videokit: Calling videokit run via loader
1576657500.860 20809-22043/com.practice.presto A/libc: **Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 22043 (Thread-19), pid 20809 (practice.presto)**
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you need to check the native libraries support , this suggestion is based on the logs that you have shared .

Please see this - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37067983

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick response

With native library support, it is working fine on sign Apk build but after uploading the same build on play store it is not working and gives this log error.